# How to save a rendered view as a static file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails 2.3 app generates a page in HTML/CSS or as a word doc. I'd like to save that html file to the filesystem as a static file (ie. filename.html or filename.doc). I plan to have a preview action w/ the fully rendered page and a 'save report' button. Our users will access those static files later. (I'll save the path to the db.)

Any suggestions for how to do this?

I'm as far as creating a file and saving it, but I'm not sure how to get my rendered view into it. Bonus points if anyone knows how to save it up to S3! Many thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`render_to_string`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string) is your friend. One you have it in a string, burn it to file in the usual way.

```
class FooController
  def save_foo_to_disk
    data = render_to_string( :action => :index )
    File.open(file_path, "w"){|f| f << data }
    flash[:notice] = "saved to #{file_path}"
  end
end
```

As far as S3 goes, see the [aws-s3 gem](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/). It seem to do what you are after. Usage is a little like this.

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
  :access_key_id     => 'abc',
  :secret_access_key => '123'
)
S3Object.store(file_name, data, 'bucket-name')
```

Have fun, and don't run with scissors.

Comment: render_to_string!!! That's fantastic. Hidden away in a short paragraph in ADwR. Worked like a charm. Once I get all the saves working, S3 will be next. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is adding an `after_action` to the controller, and in that action using `response.body` to access rendered content. In this way, your controller can respond to client as normal, save rendered content to database in meanwhile.