# Render xlsx to file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, axlsx

I wish to render xlsx template to file, using [axlsx-rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) gem. What is best way to do that?
For rendering template as **xlsx** response I'm using this line of code + template:

```
render xlsx: 'latest_buttons', template: 'featured/latest'
```

Can anyone explain a bit more about **render** function?

Comment: If you are wanting a server side file, try using render_to_string and saving the result in a file. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364830/how-to-save-a-rendered-view-as-a-static-file

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this for controller:

```
      respond_to do |format|
          format.xlsx {
            render xlsx: "report", filename: "report-#{DateTime.now.to_date}.xlsx"
          }
        end
```

Where "report" is the template and can look like this in view:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Report") do |sheet|
  sheet.add_row ["ID","Row 2"]
  @result.rows.each do |row|
    sheet.add_row [row[0], row[1]]
  end
end
```